# Aggregation calculation method for treemap in plotly.express - Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, parent, treemap

Thanks by advance for people who will try to help me. This is the first time I ask a question as I have been struggling for days on this one! Eternal glory to the one helping me out with this!

Let me explain my problem with a few lines of codes and screens.

I want to create a treemap showing the growth of values between 2 dates. In order to be more precise, I want this treemap to:
-Have squares that have a size proportional to a value x at date 2 AND be coloured according to a scale showing the growth of this value x from date 1 to date 2.

Let us consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly



data = {'variable': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'parent': ['I', 'I', 'II'],
     'value_1': [1,4,5],
     'value_2': [4,2,5]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['growth'] = 100 * (df['value_2'] / df['value_1'] - 1)

fig = px.treemap(df,  path=['parent', 'variable'], values = 'value_2', color='growth', 
                 color_continuous_scale='plasma')

fig.show()
```

It gives me the beautiful treemap here: Growth treemap

[image]

But here is the problem. As you may see on the following screen, the growth for I is 183%: a wrong growth!

[image]

However, when calculating manually, a going from 1 to 4, and b from 4 to 2, the growth should be: 1/5 * 300% + 4/5 * -50% = 20% (I goes from 5 to 6).

This is due because the calculus that is made is 4/6 * 300% + 2/6 * -50% = 183%. The method is calculating the weighting average wrt to the new coefficients, and not the former ones as it should in theory.

Is there a way, to have the correct growth when aggregating to a parent class?

Thank you very much for your help, and let me know if I can help further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get the data across as you're trying to depict it. However, I did come up with a workaround.

This requires the use of `plotly.io`.

I want to point out that the nice contrast you have with the colors is lost, when you change the parent to 20% from 183.333333--- essentially that parent is nearly the same color as II, because the values are 20 and 0, whereas 'a' is 300 and the low is only -50.

Additionally, I added `px.Constant` so that you don't get a really useless hover label for the root (the black-ish background parent of the parents).

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

fig = px.treemap(df,  path=[px.Constant('Total'), 'parent', 'variable'], 
                 values = 'value_2', color='growth', 
                 color_continuous_scale='plasma')
```

Now when you use `pio`, you will create an external file, but this is only way, short of using Jupyter, to add Javascript to your plot. This will automatically open in your browser, like `fig.show()`, except this will reflect that the parent `I` has a growth of `20%` in the hover data.

```
pio.write_html(fig, 'index.html', auto_open = True, div_id = 'thisPlot', 
               include_mathjax = 'cdn', include_plotlyjs = 'cdn', full_html = True, 
               post_script = "setTimeout(function() {" +
               "el = document.getElementById('thisPlot');" +
               "el.data[0].marker.colors[3] = 20;       /* change the calc value */" + 
               "Plotly.newPlot(el, el.data, el.layout); /* re-plot it */"
               "}, 200)")
```

You may notice that there is `el.data[0].marker.colors[3]` called to change. That's the parent `I`.

Here's all of the data that is captured in `el.data[0].marker.colors` before this change is made: `[300, -50, 0, 183.33333333333334, 0, 100]`.

By the way, whenever I go the route of `pio.write_html`, I always name the file the same thing, so it's always overwriting itself. I'm not interested in the saved file personally, just the outcome of `post_script`.